# Give an example of a function that converges to its Taylor series for $x\geq 0$ but not for $x<0$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, power-series, taylor-expansion, uniform-convergence

In Bartle Sherbert's analysis book,I found a problem.I have to construct a function such that it converges to its Taylor series on $[0,\infty)$ but not on $(-\infty,0)$.I am confused about how to approach this problem.Can someone suggest some idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take $f(x) = e^{1/x}$ for $x<0$ and $f(x)=0$ for $x\ge 0.$ You can show that $f^{(n)}(0)=0$ for every $n\ge 0.$ (For this, you may proceed inductively and use L'hopital's rule.)

Hence, the Taylor series (centred at $0$) becomes just the zero function. So this Taylor series matches with $f(x)$ for every $x\ge 0$ but does not match for every $x<0.$

Comment: Can I use any other function like $x^2$ in place of $e^{1/x}$.

Comment: Not really. The reason behind using $e^{1/x}$ is that it makes all the derivatives at $x=0$ equal zero.

Comment: Any other example?

Comment: There might exist other examples, but I think this is a classical one.

Comment: I think you used exponential because it has the property $d/dx(expx)=expx$.

Comment: Not actually. It uses $e^{1/x}$ so that for each $n$ the $n$-th derivative has that form $e^{1/x}$ times a polynomial in $1/x$ and we use L'hopital's rule to show that $e^{1/x} P(1/x) \to 0$ as $x\to 0-$, for any polynomial $P$.